# Spring integration message-store rolled back before error handler

Tags: spring-integration

I need to handle certain error conditions within my spring integration flow.  My flow is using a message store and setting the error channel on the poller.  I had thought that if I handled the message in the error handler that the rollback would not occur, but the messageStore remove (delete) is being rolled back before the error flow is even executed.

Here is a pseudo-flow that duplicates my issue.

```
<int:channel id="rollbackTestInput" >
    <int:queue message-store="messageStore"/>
</int:channel>

<int:bridge input-channel="rollbackTestInput" output-channel="createException" >
    <int:poller fixed-rate="50" 
        error-channel="myErrorChannel">
        <int:transactional />
    </int:poller>
</int:bridge>

<int:transformer input-channel="createException" output-channel="infoLogger"
    expression="T(GarbageToForceException).doesNotExist()" />

<int:channel id="myErrorChannel">
    <int:queue/> 
</int:channel>

<!-- JDBC Message Store -->
<bean id="messageStore" class="org.springframework.integration.jdbc.JdbcMessageStore">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager" >
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
```

This flow will result in an infinite rollback/poll loop.  How can I handle the error and not rollback?

Answer (score 0):

That's correct behavior. The `error-channel` logic is accepted around the TX advice for the polling task.

The code looks like:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    taskExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int count = 0;
            while (initialized && (maxMessagesPerPoll <= 0 || count < maxMessagesPerPoll)) {
                try {
                    if (!pollingTask.call()) {
                        break;
                    }
                    count++;
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    if (e instanceof RuntimeException) {
                        throw (RuntimeException) e;
                    }
                    else {
                        throw new MessageHandlingException(new ErrorMessage(e), e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Where TX Advice is on the `pollingTask.call()`, but error handling is done from the `taskExecutor`:

```
this.taskExecutor = new ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor(this.taskExecutor, this.errorHandler);
```

Where your `error-channel` is configured on that `errorHandler` as `MessagePublishingErrorHandler`.

To reach your requirements you can try to follow with [`synchronization-factory`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/transactions.html#transaction-synchronization) on the `<poller>`:

```
<int:transaction-synchronization-factory id="txSyncFactory">
    <int:after-rollback channel="myErrorChannel" />
</int:transaction-synchronization-factory>
```

Or supply your `<int:transformer>` with `<request-handler-advice-chain>`:

```
<int:request-handler-advice-chain>
    <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
        <property name="onFailureExpression" value="#exception" />
        <property name="failureChannel" value="myErrorChannel" />
        <property name="trapException" value="true" />
    </bean>
</int:request-handler-advice-chain>
```

Comment: I tried both.  All 3 options (including my original) go to the error channel. But none of the options stop the rollback.  What am I missing?

Comment: Oh! Sorry, I have missed `trapException=true` option for the `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`. Se my edit to the answer

Comment: Now I get an exception requiring a response to the transformer...I wanted to store the error and complete.  Unfortunately, the requiresReply parameter in not available on the transformer namespace and I am concerned about any impacts of setting this parameter on a normal flow.

Comment: Also...why is the poller configured to handle the error outside of the transaction flow?  This is not how it works for inbound channel adapters.  With inbound channel adapters if I handle the error, then the transaction is not rolled back.

Comment: You can return some "fake" message from your error flow to the transformer and place `<filter>` on the `infoLogger` to discard them. You "do not rollback" case is very specific, so there is really no direct solution for you.

Comment: No, they works the same way, because they extends `AbstractPollingEndpoint`

Comment: I think you have mixed that with `MessageProducer` impl, e.g. `<amqp:inbound-channel-adapter>`, which isn't pollable, but `MessageListeningEndpoint`

Comment: Thank you for all of your help...I need to digest a bit and see what can work for our scenario...thanks again for the explanation.

Comment: @Artem...Found a potential different solution.  Can you look at the other solution I am proposing and see if you see any issues with the approach?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a different solution that meets my requirements and is less invasive.

Instead of using transactional on the poller, I can use an advice chain that that specifies which exceptions I should rollback and which I shouldn't.  For my case, I do not want to rollback most exceptions.  So I rollback Throwable and list any specific exceptions I want to rollback.

```
<int:bridge input-channel="rollbackTestInput"
    output-channel="createException">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="50"
        error-channel="myErrorChannel">
        <int:advice-chain>
            <int:ref bean="txAdvice"/>
        </int:advice-chain>
    </int:poller>
</int:bridge>

<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="*" rollback-for="javax.jms.JMSException"
            no-rollback-for="java.lang.Throwable" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

Comment: @Artem  Any concerns with this approach?

Comment: Yes, that's another declarative way to make conditional rollback. Note: that `<transactional>` is just a particular case of this `<tx:advice>`.